# how to use column inside decimal or numeric in sql server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in which there is a float column 'Exchange_Rate'.
and a Defaults Table which have decimal places define for every currency.
e.g

```
Currency Decimal_Places
USD          2
CAD          6
```

I want my exchange rate to be round as per the defined decimal places..

Like

```
select decimal(20,Decimal_Places) from table
```

or

```
select numeric(20,Decimal_Places) from table
```

How can i use column inside decimal or numeric.

Comment: You'll have to do that dynamically. Even better would be to redesign the database, so you don't need to do that.

Comment: redesigning the whole database for a single column retrieval? WOW!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL for this:

```
--I use temp tables to show example
-- you must use yours
CREATE TABLE #cur(
    Exchange_Rate float
)

INSERT INTO #cur VALUES
(1.000000000),
(2.890110000),
(3.000155234)

CREATE TABLE #dec (
    Currency nvarchar(3),
    Decimal_Places int
)

INSERT INTO #dec VALUES
('USD', 2),
('CAD', 6)
--Here it comes
DECLARE @cur int, @sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @cur = Decimal_Places
FROM #dec 
WHERE Currency = 'CAD'

SELECT @sql = '
SELECT CAST(Exchange_Rate as decimal(20,'+CAST(@cur as nvarchar(10))+')) as result
FROM #cur'

EXEC sp_executesql @sql

--Here I drop temp tables
DROP TABLE #cur
DROP TABLE #dec
```

Output for `USD`:

```
result
1.00
2.89
3.00
```

Output for `CAD`

```
result
1.000000
2.890110
3.000155
```

Answer (score 2):

You can not have a column with different precision in rows in a result set, all values will be implicitly converted to single precision

```
select val=cast(5.335447 as decimal (20,2))
union all    
select val=cast(5.535447 as decimal(20,5))
```

result has precision 5

```
val
5,34000
5,53545
```

So you needn't different precision, just round()

```
with t(val, rnd) as  (
    select val=5.33544, rnd =2
    union all    
    select val=5.53544, rnd =5
)

select val=round(val,rnd)
from t;
```

Comment: i didn't get it. :(

Comment: no. multiple rows..
i do not want to hard-code inside decimal or numeric. i want it as my column. e.g decimal ( 15, columnName)

Comment: Multiple rows of the same column can not have different precision. Even if you build such a query dynamically. all values will be converted to the same precision. The only thing you'll get  - the values will be rounded. So just round them in your code.

Comment: Will the result set include values for only one currency? Then dynamic query make sence. Otherwise use round().

Comment: if i use round, myColumn = 1.22, it will not do round(myColumn,4) to 1.2200. but it will do 1.22 and finish.. decimal will do 1.2200 so that is why decimal is to be used